# Append many groups into one single dataframe python pandas (one after the other at the bottom)?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, append

can you help me with issue which I have after I got groups when I apply groupby method. Firstly I had all Report_Title land Column_Name in one file, but I separated it by doing groupby, as I wanted to apply some transformations to values in Column_Name. I did everything successfully, but at the end, I wanted to append (merge at the bottom) output with transformed values with all groups as it was at the beginning. All groups have identical name of columns.

```
groups = df.groupby('Report_Title')
 
for name, group in groups:
    group['Column_Name'] = ...
    # some successfully transformations
    # but after I wanted to append all groups into df like this: 
    data_you_need = pd.DataFrame()
    data_you_need = data_you_need.append(group, ignore_index = True)
    print(data_you_need)
    # I have got just last group
```

This is picture what I need to obtain at the end:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI8uT.png)

But unfortunately I have got in data_you_need  just last Report6 with its columns. I tried append, concat, I tried to export to csv and import again, but nothing works for me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A better pattern is to collect data in python structure like dict or list and finally create a dataframe:

```
groups = df.groupby('Report_Title')

data_you_need = [] 
for name, group in groups:
    group['Column_Name'] = ...
    data_you_need.append(group)
df = pd.concat(data_you_need)
```